# Is it possible to create custom schema in Corda open source

Tags: corda

I have one sample cordapp where I want to use Postgresql for two of my nodes (PartyA and PartyB). I have created two sql file to create both the user and schema. Below is the sql file for PartyA.

**

```
**CREATE USER "party_a" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_password';
CREATE SCHEMA "party_a_schema";
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA "party_a_schema" TO "party_a";
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON ALL tables IN SCHEMA "party_a_schema" TO "party_a";
ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA "party_a_schema" GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON tables TO "party_a";
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL sequences IN SCHEMA "party_a_schema" TO "party_a";
ALTER DEFAULT privileges IN SCHEMA "party_a_schema" GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON sequences TO "party_a";
ALTER ROLE "party_a" SET search_path = "party_a_schema";**
```

**

Below is the datasource configuration

```
dataSourceProperties {
    dataSource {
        password="admin"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
        user="party_b"
    }
    dataSourceClassName="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
}
database {
   transactionIsolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED
   schema="party_b_schema"
   runMigration=true
}
```

Both the schema are available in the Postgre database. I was getting error after running the node and on further research, I have found out that I have to use **initialiseSchema** instead of **runMigration** but where I can specify my custom schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- According to [this](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-database.html#postgresql), you can specify it in the JDBC URL string. In your case it should look like this:

  ```
  jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=party_b_schema
  ```
- On a side note, starting Corda 4.4; `corda.jar` no longer contains the the JDBC driver for PostgreSQL database, you have to download it from the Internet and place the jar file inside the `drivers` folder of your node.

Comment: It's still not working. I am getting the same error "no schema has been selected".

I have already placed the JDBC driver on the particular node drivers folder.

Comment: According to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in) it might be a matter of missing privileges. I recommend that you re-run all the commands that you used when creating the schemas (all except the `create user` and `create schema` of course).

Comment: The steps that I have followed:

1. Installed Postgre and created one custom database name "Corda-demo" for my project.
2. Created the user and schema for PartyA and PartyB using the SQL scripts which I executed on Postgre.
3. Both the schemas are available on Postgre under my custom database (Corda-demo).
4. Now I made the changes into the node.conf file for both the Party.
5. Got the above error while running the node

Comment: Ok sounds good, but can you re-run the steps (except `create user` and `create schema`) just to make sure that you didn't miss anything; then try to start the nodes again.

Comment: I did a small mistake. I was using `postgres` instead of `Corda-demo` as the database name. Now, I change the database name and it's working fine.

dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://[HOST]:[PORT]/[DATABASE]"